# SONAR 3.7.3 database update failure - JDBC Error

Tags: sonarqube

After installing SONAR 3.7.3 I received the following error on startup: "o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility  Database must be upgraded. Please browse /setup"

I then followed instructions to upgrade the databse by navigating to http://:/setup.  However, when I click update databse I get the following error

---

The migration failed: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table : ALTER TABLE reviews ADD manual_severity NUMBER(1).
Please check the logs.

---

I can see, as the message suggests that the table reviews already exist and it already contains the column manual_severity, so I'm not sure why its trying to re-add it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a backup of the database schema and start the process again from the beginning.

If you don't have a backup, I cannot see any other way than to delete the column in your schema and try to migrate the database again, but you might find a lot of errors of this kind and have to repeat this operation some times. Also, you will never be sure that your DB is Ok.